# Get MySQL cursor rowcount without fetching

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm using Python MySQL Connector and I want to know how many rows my select statement returned without having to fetch them first. Example code I'm using:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'user': 'sample_user',
    'password': 'sample_password',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'sample_database'
    }

connection = mysql.connector.connect(**self.config)

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM sample_table
        """

cursor.execute(query)

count = cursor.rowcount 
print(count) # This prints -1 as the rows have not yet been fetched

i = 0
for row in cursor:
    i += 1
    # Save row to file
    print("Progress {:2.1%}".format(i / count), end="\r") # This prints a negative number since count is -1
```

I want to show the fetching progress but for this I need the total count of rows selected with the `SELECT` statement before fetching.

Is there a way to retrieve the rowcount without fetching or running a seperate `SELECT COUNT(*)` query first?

Comment: AFAIK if you want to log your progress this way you should send (at least) 2 requests: first for getting records count and second (and next ones) with fetching records

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you have stored the row count value otherwise.

And actually neither the cursor object will give a streamed result, you should iterate the whole table batch by batch via limit/offset keywords.

Comment: Are you sure about the last part? Just executing the query happens in less than a second, while the actual fetching takes multiple minutes.